# Show different version of view using query parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have got a view which presents a list of objects.

```
public partial class Book
{   
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public int TitleId { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public int pages { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to present the view with different parameters. I want to show books with the title which is "C# for Begginers", another time I want to show books with the author who is "M. Smith", and another time with both of these parameters, etc.

What is the best approach to achieve that? I want to have a controller method with all of these parameters, and check which of them are set, but it will require a lot of ifs, I hope that there is a better way.

This is how I get a list from database:

```
var list = context.Book.Where(i => i.TitleId == titleid).ToList();
```

Is it possible to include conditions in this lambda expression? If it could be checked if value is assigned, that would help me a lot.

Comment: Get title list with child books collection. that will be easy to handle

Comment: I think you should finalize the UI design first.

Comment: @ssilas777 I did. Did you read the question?

Comment: @stkvhw, I read, but didn't see any wire frame screenshots or image links, better provide that for more response.

Comment: I don't see why I should do that, it's just a view with list of books with some details. If something is unclear, please tell me.

Comment: Oops! so you are just asking about how to include conditions in linq query. your title is bit confusing.

Comment: not really, maybe there are another ways to achieve what I want, it doesn't have to be with linq query.

Comment: Show how you are currently calling the view. That way we can assist. There is no Indication of what the controller looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it sort of sounds like you already know what you need to do, but don't want to because it "will require a lot of ifs". I'm not sure what other method you expect to find, but it's going to have to be something like:

```
public ActionResult Books(string title, string author)
{
    var books = context.Book.AsQuerable();

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
    {
        books = books.Where(m => m.Title == title);
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(author))
    {
        books = books.Where(m => m.Author == author);
    }

    return View(books);
}
```

In other words, you have to determine whether or not the filtering param was passed (your `if` statement) and then conditionally filter the collection of books, accordingly.

**EDIT**

Well, I sort of take that back. You don't *technically* need `if` statements, but the code is *much* more readable and obvious that way. If you just have an unhealthy fixation with avoiding `if`s at all costs, you could do something like:

```
var books = context.Book.Where(m => (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title) || m.Title == title) && (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(author) || m.Author == author));
```

Comment: Thank you. I went with the first option.